# state is present but all of the following are missing: source

Tags: docker, ansible

I have Ansible script to build docker image:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: build docker image
    docker_image:
      name: bionic
      path: /
      force: yes
    tags: deb
```

and Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive; \
  apt-get -qq update && \
  apt-get -qq install \
  software-properties-common git curl wget openjdk-8-jre-headless debhelper devscripts
WORKDIR /workspace
```

when I run next command: `ansible-playbook build.yml -vvv`
I received next exception.

```
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/devpc/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1633701673.999151-517949-133730725910177/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
"changed": false,
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "api_version": "auto",
        "archive_path": null,
        "build": null,
        "ca_cert": null,
        "client_cert": null,
        "client_key": null,
        "debug": false,
        "docker_host": "unix://var/run/docker.sock",
        "force": true,
        "force_absent": false,
        "force_source": false,
        "force_tag": false,
        "load_path": null,
        "name": "xroad-deb-bionic",
        "path": "/",
        "pull": null,
        "push": false,
        "repository": null,
        "source": null,
        "ssl_version": null,
        "state": "present",
        "tag": "latest",
        "timeout": 60,
        "tls": false,
        "tls_hostname": null,
        "use_ssh_client": false,
        "validate_certs": false
    }
},
"msg": "state is present but all of the following are missing: source"
}
```

Could you please give me a hint how to debug and understand what this error mean?
Thanks for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error says a `source:` key must be present in the `docker_image:` block.

More specifically, most things in Ansible default to `state: present`.  When you request a [`docker_image`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_image_module.html#ansible-collections-community-docker-docker-image-module) to be present, there are a couple of ways to get it (pulling it from a registry, building it from source, unpacking it from a tar file).  Which way to do this is specified by the `source:` control, but Ansible does not have a default value for this.

If you're building an image, you need to specify `source: build`.  Having done that, there are also a set of controls under `build:`.  In particular, the path to the Docker image context (probably not `/`) goes there and not directly under `docker_image:`.

This leaves you with something like:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: build docker image
    docker_image:
      name: bionic
      source: build  # <-- add
      build:         # <-- add
        path: /home/user/src/something  # <-- move under build:
      force: yes
    tags: deb
```

Comment: Jeez, ChatGPT went circles giving weird ideas about this error, instead of just suggesting this thing which solves the problem.  here is what chatgpt had to say about the error, it gave different "useless" suggestions but none worked.      The error "state is present but all of the following are missing: source" is somewhat generic but typically means that Ansible's docker_image module is expecting some kind of "source" to build or pull the image from and can't find it.

Comment: @Piepypye same thing here. Just only goes to show that we can't depend on bots all the time!